# Error dialog displayed opening an excel file generated with EPPlus

Tags: excel, epplus, epplus-4

Generated excel from EPPLUS issue 
When excel is opened it displays an error saying we found a problem with some content in Excel. Do you want us to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an issue with EPPLUS 4.1.1, Below is the link for the issue registered on github.

We downgraded to the version to 4.0.5 which works fine.

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/issues/38